# what programs can be installed in a docker container

Tags: docker, environment

I am a Windows user.

I have looked at the official Docker tutorial "Get Started". The example focus is a python app. I don't know python and I guess a Docker container can have many programs installed as an environment, not just python.

1. Is Docker good for testing a program I download from the internet in an isolated environment (like a sandbox in firewalls or antivirus) ?
2. How for example can I make a container that has an environment containing installed programs like Visual Studio, VLC player, Office, etc.?

Thanks,
Abe

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes; you can have an isolated environment with `docker`. You can set your desired configurations, download from internet, install, and whatever you do in a Virtual Machine.
2. Yes, you can. What your container contains depends on the base image you create it `FROM` and packages you install inside of it.

**Tips**

1. You can build your container from an empty OS (e.g. `ubuntu`), configure the OS, download/install/configure/run whatever you want.
2. You can create a base image which derives `FROM` a suitable OS, then install any basic application (e.g. firefox) which you may use in a lot of containers on it. Then you should `push` it in a registry (e.g. Github). After that, you can use it as a base image for other containers, so your new containers have installed applications by default; no need to install them again. It reduces complexity and repetitions in `Dockerfile`.

Comment: "You can create a base image which derives FROM a suitable OS, then install any basic application (e.g. firefox) which you may use in a lot of containers on it. Then you should push it in a registry (e.g. Github). After that, you can use it as a base image for other containers, so your new containers have installed applications by default; no need to install them again. It reduces complexity and repetitions in Dockerfile." 
_______________
I am glad to hear I can. From the tutorial I mentioned, I couldn't understand how to do that. Can you direct me to a tutorial specifically doing that ?

Comment: I can't name a tutorial; I learned it from googling and trying except [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) for windows. BTW, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/seansummers/docker-jython). Since you mentioned that you are a windows user, [this one](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/) would be helpful too.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks